# How to have hover effects on input boxes in Internet Explorer 6

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im looking how to have hover effects on input boxes in Internet Explorer 6? Im using YUI if I can utilise that.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which problem did you get? Did you make it run in e.g. IE7? Show us some code ...

Comment: Aren't '...' annoying? 
Anyway to update others Ive implemented powtac's solution and coupled it with YAHOO.util.Selector.query to obtain specific classes. However I have hit another wall. Most content is Ajax. So when the selector is run it only picks up whats in the container. Am I going to have to run YAHOO.util.Selector.query('classname') on every page?

Answer (score 0):

Try this javascript:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var hoverOn = function() {
    this.className = "hover";
};
var hoverOff = function() {
    this.className = "";
};
for (var i = 0, l = inputs.length; i < l; ++i) {
    inputs[i].onmouseover = hoverOn; 
    inputs[i].onmouseout = hoverOff;
}
```

And the CSS:

```
input.hover {
    background-color: #f0f;
}
```

Here's the above, which works in Firefox... let me know how IE6 goes... http://jsbin.com/aseli

Comment: You'll likely want to exclude Button, Checkbox, Radio, Submit, Reset & Image types from the collection of "input" elements.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="elementid" />
```

JS:

```
var oElement = document.getElementById("elementid"); 
function fnCallback(e) { alert("mouse over"); } 
YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(oElement, "mouseover", fnCallback);
```

Taken from http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/event/#start

Comment: you're going to add an id to every input element?

Comment: No it is not required! You just must tell Javascript which of the input fields is your target. Post your input field and we will find a better selector.

Comment: Hi that is perfect. Ive coupled it with YAHOO.util.Selector.query to obtain specific classes. However I have hit another wall. Most content is Ajax. So when the selector is run it only picks up whats in the container. Am I going to have to run YAHOO.util.Selector.query('classname') on every page?